# Manage Async, non-cpu intensive task on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, iis

Sometime my ASP.NET site have to call external service, download or upload small files on FTP/SFTP or other task that can require time. In the worst case of a connection timeout it can get even 30 seconds.

Right now my asp.net site runs on a single AppPool so, if a request to an external service requires 5 seconds, my entire AppPoll is froze for that time (and so all my users).

Thats because 99% of the times the request time is very fast so i don't care if the user has to wait 0.5 seconds to a page load. But i'm not happy that every other user have to wait that 0.5 seconds too.

I asked to friend and collegue and they said i have to create a "job" for every long task. Put my job request in a shared database, let an external program (daemon, service, whatever) handle that job, write the result on the DB and let the user pool (or longpool) a page to know when its request is complete.

This looks like an over-kill to a simple non-cpu intensive task. Is there a way to make requests (or request that do not involve session state, i accept that also) non AppPool blocking?

Comment: I think your friend and colleague has given you right suggestion Follow it Not necessarily your job and app has to communicate via db there are plenty of other options like RebbitMQ,Service Bus etc.

Comment: Unless you're working with very old .NET or highly unusual communications, there's almost certainly a way to send the request to the external service and get a `Task` back that represents the response arriving back from the service. Use that method instead of you're current one, use `async` and `await` all the way up from where that service is called until we hit the controller/page methods, and then *when there's work to be done*, the TPL/`await` will take care of running the code that still needs to.

Comment: In good, I/O based code, there should be [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)'s/tasks being manually created.

Comment: "But i'm not happy that every other user have to wait that 0.5 seconds too." How does your code look like? It is impossible that every other user is affected (as every requests are handled separately, so I can only say your code is incorrect. Surprisingly your friend and colleague didn't notice the red flag.

Comment: True - if you have a website that is only processing *one request at a time*, that's the first problem you should look to solve.

Comment: @LexLi my code looks like ```var something = SFTPClient.Download(file);```, thats the blocking procedure, but even a simple http request will produce the same blocking result. 

@Damien_The_Unbeliever even if i use async await i cannot produce a response for the user until my long operation is complete, and if i produce a response istantly i cannot give the user that data since i still don't have it

@ChiragMM sigh, i think i will do it in someway. Thank you!

Comment: So you only has a single `SFTPClient` and only one connection to the external service is allowed? If so, that's horrible and no real solution can remove the bottleneck.